# C struggling with getline() - incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: c, user-input, getline

I need my program to gather random user input in order to return the number of character as odd or even (`return ( strlen ( &raw_scrap ) % 2 ) ;`)

I can't get the `getline()` function to work properly from `char raw_scrap` global declaration.

Here are the warnings I get:

```
$clang geomant.c -o geomant.bin
geomant.c:61:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char **' [-Wint-conversion]
        getline ( raw_scrap, sizeof(&raw_scrap), stdin ) ;
                  ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:239:36: note: passing argument to parameter here
ssize_t  getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict,
                                   ^
geomant.c:61:23: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned long' to parameter of type 'size_t *' (aka 'unsigned long *') [-Wint-conversion]
        getline ( raw_scrap, sizeof(&raw_scrap), stdin ) ;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:239:57: note: passing argument to parameter here
ssize_t  getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict,
                                                        ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Here's my full code (omit repetitive arrays for compactness/readability):

```
/*****************************************/
/*     Geomant : a basic implementation  */
/*  of the geomanteia intended as a first*/
/*  C training project                   */
/*  copyright \xc2\xa9 Sylvain Saboua    */
/*  <sylvain ! saboua (|) free ! fr>     */
/*****************************************/

# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <unistd.h>

char *body_parts[] = { "head", "neck", "body", "legs" } ;
char *mother_figures[] = { "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th" } ;

int n_figure ;
int n_bodypart ;

char raw_scrap ;
char *figures[15][4] = {
        // mothers
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},

        // daughters
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},

        // nieces
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},

        // witnesses & judge
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"},
        {"* *", "* *", "* *", "* *"}
} ;

/*

        "mantize" : input fuction

 This function gathers a string of user input
 and returns a 0 or 1 for the evenness or
 oddity of the number of characters. It is called
 in a sequence by the next function to generate
 the figures one by one.

*/

int mantize ( int n_bodypart, int n_figure ) {
        printf ( "Hold or repeatedly press a key or keys to generate the %s of the %s mother
, then press Enter:\n",
                body_parts[n_bodypart], mother_figures[n_figure] ) ;
        getline ( raw_scrap, sizeof(&raw_scrap), stdin ) ;
        return ( strlen ( &raw_scrap ) % 2 ) ;
}

/*

        "generate" fuction:

 This function takes the cast result (being 0 or 1,
 odd or even) and use it to generate
 all 15 figures, from the mothers down to the
 daughters, nieces, witnesses and judge.

*/

int generate(){

        // generating the mothers

        for ( n_figure = 0 ; n_figure < 4 ; n_figure++ ) {
                for ( n_bodypart = 0 ; n_bodypart < 4 ; n_bodypart++ ) {
                        figures[n_figure][n_bodypart] =
                        (0 == mantize(n_bodypart, n_figure)) ? "* *" : "*" ;
                }
        }

        //generating the four daughters from the four mothers

        figures[4][0] = figures[0][0] ;
        figures[4][1] = figures[1][0] ;
        figures[4][2] = figures[2][0] ;
        figures[4][3] = figures[3][0] ;

        figures[5][0] = figures[0][1] ;
        figures[5][1] = figures[1][1] ;
        figures[5][2] = figures[2][1] ;
        figures[5][3] = figures[3][1] ;

        figures[6][0] = figures[0][2] ;
        figures[6][1] = figures[1][2] ;
        figures[6][2] = figures[2][2] ;
        figures[6][3] = figures[3][2] ;

        figures[7][0] = figures[0][3] ;
        figures[7][1] = figures[1][3] ;
        figures[7][2] = figures[2][3] ;
        figures[7][3] = figures[3][3] ;

        // generating the nieces

        figures[8][0] = ( figures[0][0] == figures[1][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[8][1] = ( figures[0][1] == figures[1][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[8][2] = ( figures[0][2] == figures[1][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[8][3] = ( figures[0][3] == figures[1][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        figures[9][0] = ( figures[2][0] == figures[3][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[9][1] = ( figures[2][1] == figures[3][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[9][2] = ( figures[2][2] == figures[3][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[9][3] = ( figures[2][3] == figures[3][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        figures[10][0] = ( figures[4][0] == figures[5][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[10][1] = ( figures[4][1] == figures[5][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[10][2] = ( figures[4][2] == figures[5][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[10][3] = ( figures[4][3] == figures[5][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        figures[11][0] = ( figures[6][0] == figures[7][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[11][1] = ( figures[6][1] == figures[7][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[11][2] = ( figures[6][2] == figures[7][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[11][3] = ( figures[6][3] == figures[7][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        // generating the witnesses

        figures[12][0] = ( figures[8][0] == figures[9][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[12][1] = ( figures[8][1] == figures[9][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[12][2] = ( figures[8][2] == figures[9][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[12][3] = ( figures[8][3] == figures[9][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        figures[13][0] = ( figures[10][0] == figures[11][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[13][1] = ( figures[10][1] == figures[11][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[13][2] = ( figures[10][2] == figures[11][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[13][3] = ( figures[10][3] == figures[11][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        //generating the judge

        figures[14][0] = ( figures[12][0] == figures[13][0] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[14][1] = ( figures[12][1] == figures[13][1] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[14][2] = ( figures[12][2] == figures[13][2] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;
        figures[14][3] = ( figures[12][3] == figures[13][3] ) ? "* *" : " * " ;

        return *figures[14][3] ;

}


/*

        "display" function:

 This function will display onscreen the final
 geomantic Shield for the given divination.
 The "-" & "|" characters are used for separation
 while the dots are displayed using "*"

*/
int main(){

        generate();

        //printf(*figures);

        /*
        printf(" --- ")
        for i in .*
        return(*raw_scrap[3][3]);
        */

}
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). The learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: please note that you are using getline wrong, check out the man pages on getline. it is for reading lines, not characters

Comment: I also suggest you take more time to read about [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). It doesn't work as you seem to expect. You also seem to misunderstand how the string functions works, or what a string really is. All standard string functions (like `strlen`) expects a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string. If you pass something else, then that leads to *undefined behavior*. You might want to take a few steps back and refresh the basic of C and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `getline()`.  You're passing a `char` value as `getline()`'s first argument, instead of the required `char **` pointer-to-pointer-to-`char`.

Per the [POSIX `getline()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getline.html) (Pay particular attention to the bolded second paragraph of the description section):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> ssize_t getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n,
>        int delimiter, FILE *restrict stream);
> ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n,
>        FILE *restrict stream);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `getdelim()` function shall read from stream until it encounters a character matching the delimiter character. The delimiter
> argument is an `int`, the value of which the application shall ensure
> is a character representable as an `unsigned char` of equal value that
> terminates the read process. If the delimiter argument has any other
> value, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero,
> the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an
> object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a `null` pointer.**
>
> If `*lineptr` is a `null` pointer or if the object pointed to by
> `*lineptr` is of insufficient size, an object shall be allocated as if
> by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`,
> respectively, such that the object is large enough to hold the
> characters to be written to it, including the terminating `NUL`, and
> `*n` shall be set to the new size. If the object was allocated, or if
> the reallocation operation moved the object, `*lineptr` shall be
> updated to point to the new object or new location. The characters
> read, including any delimiter, shall be stored in the object, and a
> terminating `NUL` added when the delimiter or end-of-file is
> encountered.
>
> The `getline()` function shall be equivalent to the `getdelim()` function with the delimiter character equal to the `<newline>` character.

A correct use of `getline()` would look more like this:

```
char *raw_scrap = NULL;
size_t raw_scrap_size = 0UL;
   .
   .
   .
        getline ( &raw_scrap, &raw_scrap_size, stdin ) ;
```

`getline()` reads an entire line of input - you'll have to change your program to work with lines, not individual `char` inputs.

Note that `raw_scrap` must be a **pointer** to `char` and the **address** of that pointer must be passed to `getline()`, and the second argument is the address of an actual `size_t` **variable**, not a constant result from calling `sizeof()`, which isn't an address.

Note also the values contained in those arguments must comply with the restrictions noted in the POSIX standard.